# How do I validate that target="_blank" exists after a given link?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a link which I can validate correctly which is followed by the code `target="_blank"`. I do not wish to click the link as it takes me outside of the system I am testing and requires a new login. What I want to do is simply validate `target="_blank"` is shown after the link. I am working in Selenium webdriver and C#

```
//  Try and find the link for eTMAs http://www.open.ac.uk/assessment/documents/New-eTMA-Interface_000.pdf
string eTMAslink = "http://www.open.ac.uk/assessment/documents/New-eTMA-Interface_000.pdf";
Console.WriteLine($"Checking for eTMAs link http://www.open.ac.uk/assessment/documents/New-eTMA-Interface_000.pdf");
IWebElement eTMAsLink = Globals.GetElementByhref(eTMAslink);
Assert.IsNotNull(eTMAsLink);
Console.WriteLine($"Found eTMAsLink link ", eTMAsLink);

// Now validate target="_blank"> how?
```

Answer (score 1):

`IWebElement`defines the [`GetAttribute`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method that you can use to check whether the *attribute* `target` is present on the link, e.g.:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(eTMAsLink);
var targetValue = eTMAslink.GetAttribute("target");
Assert.AreEqual("_blank", targetValue);
```

Comment: @DaveK good to hear that it worked. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you handle exception. You may try to improve your code for asserting **about:blank**

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using NUnit.Framework;

  public void checknewTab(IWebDriver driver)
    {
       try
      {
        /* New tab window with  IJavaScriptExecutor */
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("window.open();");

        /* Switch driver to last tab [which is blank tab] */
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last()); 

        /* Verify new Tab by using Assert  If it is was not about:blank - 
        It will throw AssertionException */

        Assert.AreEqual("about:blank", driver.Url); 
      }
     catch(AssertionException ex)
      {
           /* Print [Console.Writeline] that there is not a new Tab 
           [about:blank] */
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
     {
        // Print to see other Exception 
     }


    }
```